# Automatically add a jquery date picker to all [DataType(DataType.Date)] fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` on properties in our models.

How can I make Razor add the css class `datepicker` to all text boxes which belongs to `DataType.Date` properties? (so that I can add date pickers using jquery on document load)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

[Integrating with the jQuery UI date picker and adding a jQuery validate date range validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)